# Cannot connect with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have problems with connecting with mongo.

```
me@the_host:~$ mongo

MongoDB shell version v4.0.0
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2018-06-28T17:06:37.445+0200 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

I went to `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log` to see:

```
2018-06-28T17:16:11.763+0200 I COMMAND  [initandlisten] Assigning UUID b237b94b-b3a3-4ba1-9c39-c87d6f3555db to collection local.startup_log
2018-06-28T17:16:11.764+0200 F STORAGE  [initandlisten] Unable to start up mongod due to missing featureCompatibilityVersion document.
2018-06-28T17:16:11.764+0200 F STORAGE  [initandlisten] Please run with --journalOptions 4 to recover the journal. Then run with --repair to restore the document.
2018-06-28T17:16:11.764+0200 F -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 40652 at src/mongo/db/repair_database_and_check_version.cpp 555
2018-06-28T17:16:11.764+0200 F -        [initandlisten]
```

I executed `mongod --journalOptions 4` and then `mongod --repair` but the error is still the same.
I have no idea what to do next..

Could anybody, who overcame this before, point me to proper direction?

Comment: Did you set featureCompatibilityVersion before upgrading to v4?

Comment: @AlexBlex No. Initially I installed default MongoDB version from Ubuntu 16.04, which turned out to be 2.7.
I purged it and went through https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/ with version 4.0 and now I can't connect with `mongo`..

Comment: `rm -rf` data directory (it is defined in storage.dbPath in the config). Previous version left some residuals there. Then start mongod again. **You will loose all data** if any.

Comment: Great. It works!